# Getting emacs realgud:pry to work

Tags: emacs, pry, ruby-debug

Need some help getting realgud to play nice with pry-remote.

This is a sample ruby file (x.rb)

```
require 'pry-remote'

class Foo
  def initialize(x, y)
    binding.remote_pry
    puts "hello"
  end
end

Foo.new(1,3)
```

In a *shell* buffer:

```
bash: ruby x.rb
[pry-remote] Waiting for client on druby://127.0.0.1:9876

# check that I have a listening process
bash: ss -nlt
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128               127.0.0.1:9876                     *:*
```

In emacs:

```
M-x realgud:pry
pry-remote ; enter this at the prompt
```

This is what I see in emacs;

```
File Edit Options Buffers Tools Inf-Ruby Debugger Help

    32:   end
    33:
    34:   return_value
    35: end

=>[0G[1] pry(#<PryNav::Tracer>)>

-=--:**--F1  *pry +No filename+ shell*   Bot L53    (Comint:r
      stop unless RUBY_VERSION == '1.9.2'

      return_value = nil
      command = catch(:breakout_nav) do      # Coordinates w$
        return_value = yield
=>      {}    # Nothing thrown == no navigational command
      end

-=--:%%--F1  tracer.rb      24% L21    (Ruby ShortKeys) ---
```

My question is: why am I seeing the breakpoint in tracer.rb? How do I get the breakpoint
to be in  my source file?

Hitting 'n' twice in the source window causes the *shell* buffer to echo the following, but there
is no change in the source window itself.

```
=>[0G[1] pry(#<PryNav::Tracer>)> next 1
next 1
```

Also, the 'u' and 'd' keystrokes yield

```
Command down is not implemented for this debugger
Command up is not implemented for this debugger
```